# How to integrate RazorPay Auto Capture?

Tags: java, android, payment-gateway, razorpay

I want to integrate RazorPay Auto capture in my Android App. I have integrated payment sdk for android. Now how to integrate Razor Pay Orders API?

I have integrated RazorPay Android sdk for payment in Android App as in the sample app.

https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-android-sample-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/razorpay/sampleapp/PaymentActivity.java

It's working fine.

Now I have to integrate Auto capture. Can anyone tell me how to do that? I have read the official doc for Orders API.

https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/orders/

But it shows backend firing orders API. In my implementation, I am doing the payment in front end and only passing the success to Backend. Where should I include the Orders API in this flow? before the payment or after the payment?
Also how to do the last step, that is, Signature verification?

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same situation, did you find the solution?

Comment: have you find the solution if yes can you please post it .